# translating Objective-C to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I need help translating this to swift. Any ideas?

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pushMessage, @"alert", @"increment", @"badge",  nil];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113

Comment: Why did you just delete your prior question, asking exactly the same thing?

Comment: Next time if you need any translation from Objective-C, try using Swiftify before asking.

https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize that dictionary in swift, as shown below, and end up with an equivalent NSDictionary:

```
let data : NSDictionary = [  "alert" : pushMessage, "badge" : "increment" ]
```

See [Apple's section on collection types within the Swift programming language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) for more detail.

Hope that helps!